# Find current step in a series of numbers

Tags: c, algorithm, math

I try to create a simple function in C which permit us to find the current step of a series of number by giving the current line number, the total number of lines, and the number of steps...

Example of numbers series :

```
line 0  - 0   --
line 1  - 0     |--> STEP 1
line 2  - 0   --
line 3  - 1   --
line 4  - 1     |--> STEP 2
line 5  - 1     |
line 6  - 1   --
line 7  - 2   --
line 8  - 2     |
line 9  - 2     |--> STEP 3
line 10 - 2     |
line 11 - 2   --

Parameters : currentLine = 5; totalLines = 12; steps = 3;
```

I have three different steps in this case, all steps are incremented by one more line. Each step is represented by the same number, next to line numbers.

In my example, I choose currentLine = 5, which represents the line where we want to find the current step. So in my case I need to find : 2.

My prototype of my function giving the current step of the current line :

```
int findCurrentStep(int currentLine, int totalLines, int steps);
```

I just want to know how to calculate it ?

EDIT : Thank you for your answers, I just made another method.

```
int findCurrentStep(int currentLine, int totalLines, int steps)
{
    int step;
    int trim_lines;

    step = steps;
    trim_lines = totalLines;
    while (currentLine <= trim_lines -1)
    {
        trim_lines = totalLines - 3 + steps - 1;
        step--;
    }
    return step;
}
```

This works with just one step, but no several ones...

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? Why doesn't your current solution work, if there is any?

Comment: What do you mean by "I have three different steps in this case, all steps are incremented by one more line."

Comment: @vish4071 I think that by incrementing step, the number of lines is incremented by one (step 0 - 3 lines, step 1 - 4 lines ...)

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstand, "steps" are  represented by the same number, (example : line 0 to 2 is step 1)

Comment: Is it like, there are 3 steps in total (0,1,2) and in every case (not just this one), they increase by 1. (like 0 occurs 3 times so 1 "WILL" occur 4 times and so on)

Comment: @mickaelb91 - Your question is extremely poorly worded. Add proper illustrations, for what is currentLine, what is steps? in the question itself. Give a sample example. From what have I understood, I've added an answer.

Comment: Sorry for that, I edited my question.

Comment: @mickaelb91, see my answer. I guess it answers your general case scenario

Comment: @mickaelb91 - Do you have any problem with our approach? I don't see why adding those confusing lines in your code will serve your purpose? Doesn't my pseudo-code serve what you expected???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT : -**

This is a 1-step solution.

You need to find that the currentLine is equal or less than which first r-terms of the AP starting with 3. The first term whose sum overall surpasses currentLine would be the currentStep.

Let's suppose that currentLine is less than or equal to sum of first ***r***  terms of AP.

So, currentLine <= 3 + ... + 3 + (r-1) * 1.

PSEUDO-CODE :-

```
initialStep = 3;  // initialStep is 3 in this case.
sum = currentLine;  .
currentStep = 0;
while(sum > initialStep){
   sum -= initialStep;
   initialStep = intialStep + 1;
   currentStep++;
}
requiredAnswer = currentStep + 1;
```

Your answer would be (currentStep + 1) after the loop as the loop would be terminated when the condition would fail.

Answer (score 0):

If there are `x` steps and `n` total lines, let number of times 1st step occurs is `a`.
Then, as problem suggests,

```
a + (a+1) + (a+2) + ... + (a+x-1) = n  //since x steps and n total lines
```

So, this implies,

```
x * (2*a + x - 1) = 2*n
```

Now, since we know `x` and `n`, solve for `a`.

Once you know `a`, if your "to find" current line is `c`, you can see for which `k`, this inequality is satisfied:

```
a + (a+1) + ... (a+k) < c <= a + (a+1) + ...(a+k+1)
```

Then, `k+1` will be your answer.